# How do I get the value of the selected item in a datalist using pure JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a datalist as follows:

```
<input data-row-id="1" id="assignee[1]" name="assignment[1][assignee]" class="assignee" list="transcribers" autocomplete="off" value="" onchange="showEditing(this);" data-id-proofinglevel="1" data-transcriber-id="1361">
<datalist id="transcribers">
    <option value="" data-id="0" data-id-proofinglevel=""></option>
    <option value="Amy" data-id="674" data-id-proofinglevel="1"></option>
    <option value="Jack" data-id="113" data-id-proofinglevel="2"></option>
</datalist>
```

In another part of my code, I need to get the data-id-proofinglevel for the matching data-id using PHP or vanilla JavaScript. I am clueless as to how to do that.

I tried using this to get the proofing level:

```
let proofingLevel = document.getElementById('assignee[' + rowid + ']').getAttribute('data-id-proofinglevel');
```

but it brings in the wrong number. If I try

```
let list = document.getElementById('transcribers');
let proofingLevel = list.options[list.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id-proofinglevel');`
```

I get undefined.

TIA.

Comment: Based on your code how many groups of input/datalist do you have? You can only have one unique id on a page, so if you have more than one datalist with an id="transcribers" it won't work properly. You should have a think about using a data attribute for your input id too.

Comment: @Andy, there are other datalists, but only one with an id of transcribers. This is existing code that I'm working with, so I don't want to change too much if I don't have to. What should I use for the input id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDataListElement) elements don't have a `selectedIndex` property.

As far as I can tell, you get the value from the `input` and then find the `option` with that value, like this:

```js
function showEditing(input) {
    // Get the value from the input
    var value = input.value;
    // Get the matching `option` element from the `datalist` (which is
    // available via `input.list`)
    var option = Array.prototype.find.call(input.list.options, function(option) {
        return option.value === value;
    });
    // Get its `data-id` attribute value
    console.log(option.getAttribute("data-id"));
}
```

```html
<input data-row-id="1" id="assignee[1]" name="assignment[1][assignee]" class="assignee" list="transcribers" autocomplete="off" value="" onchange="showEditing(this);" data-id-proofinglevel="1" data-transcriber-id="1361">
<datalist id="transcribers">
    <option value="" data-id="0" data-id-proofinglevel=""></option>
    <option value="Amy" data-id="674" data-id-proofinglevel="1"></option>
    <option value="Jack" data-id="113" data-id-proofinglevel="2"></option>
</datalist>
```

---

Note [Andy's point in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493879/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-the-selected-item-in-a-datalist-using-pure-js/57494017#comment101457683_57493879), though.

Answer (score 0):

fetch datalist value using javascript

```
function showEditing(input) {
  var datalist = "";
  var list = document.getElementById('transcribers').children;
  for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    var data = list[i];
    datalist = data.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log(datalist);
  }
}
```